# Spatie\MediaLibrary error, argument #1 ($model) must be of type Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia, App\Models\Post given

Tags: laravel

Laravel [Spatie Media Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction) is not working. Using Laravel 10.10 and spatie media 10.0.

I did all the things as described at official docs.

Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Post extends Model
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body',
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
public function postUploadImage(Request $request, Post $post) 
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:200',
    ]);
    $post->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images');
    return back();
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.postUploadImage', $post->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::patch('/post-upload-image/{post}', [PostController::class, 'postUploadImage'])->name('postUploadImage');
```

Error:

> Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\FileAdder::processMediaItem(): Argument #1 ($model) must be of type Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia, App\Models\Post given, called in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\laravel-example\vendor\spatie\laravel-medialibrary\src\MediaCollections\FileAdder.php on line 428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't prepare your [model](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/basic-usage/preparing-your-model) correctly, it's missing the `implements` operator.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Post extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
}
```